# website dont save /update content and any setting

Tags: 7, installation, iis, database

I am develop in my laptop a drupal 7 on this enviroment: Windows 7 + IIS 7 + MSSQL Server 2008 R2 , its run fine. But when we upload to the webserver (Windows Server R8 + IIS 7 + MSSQL Server 2008 R2) and restore a backup of the database. The website don't save / update content and any change of settings for modules, site configuration, etc.. Drupal dont show error and the php log dont show warnings.

If you know about we can resolve this issue, please help me.

Comment: URL Rewrite Module enabled?

Comment: Yes. Its enable and resolve the urls fine. The trouble is when i'm trying to save or update any content or setting.... Please dont erase this comment, because its in repply to he comment before this. (i'm the question owner)

Comment: Any browser console errors when you hit the save button?

Comment: Hi @rdaniel, I've converted your answer to a comment - please make sure to leave answers only for answers to the question in future. If you own the post, you'll be able to comment on it

Comment: Do you have the same permissions on the schema on the remote server as on your dev machine?  This sounds like a SQL permission issue (ie, your user can't INSERT or UPDATE).

Comment: Please help-me, i go to edit and after save, and after e publish content.

Comment: Have you checked the SQL permission of the user you're using? comment see just above. Try to update a random variable in a DB table and see if it works and use the same credential in settings.php .